# Resetting mathcal font to default

Tags: fonts

I am using the package `mathptmx` to change the text font to Times. However, the mathcal font is changed as well, which is think is a bit ugly.

How can I reset the mathcal font to its default?

Comment: If you just want to change the text fonts, use `times` package, or use `newtxtext` as Juri Robl said.

Answer (score 69):

Add the following line to your preamble:

```
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathcal}{OMS}{cmsy}{m}{n}
```

Comment: Thanks, that does the trick. The advantage of this approach is that only the mathcal alphabet is reset, whereas the others stay as defined by `mathptmx`

Comment: I am using `\usepackage{cmbright}` which doesn't render any `\mathcal` glyphs.  I was hoping to restore them by adding `\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathcal}{OMS}{cmsy}{m}{n}`, it complains that `\mathcal` is already defined.  Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: @QuantumDot A simple document calling just `\usepackage{cmbright}` prints `\mathcal{A}` as expected. Please, ask a new question with a minimal example.

Comment: For more explanations, also see : [Using computer modern \rightarrow with fourier font](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/136339/116936)

Comment: Thanks! I want to use `fouriernc` but for some reason it sets `\mathcal` to look like what is normally understood as `\mathscr`. This fixes it (and using the same characters as CM is probably a benefit in terms of being understood correctly).

Answer (score 3):

I restored `\boldmath` to make sure that bold version is available.

```
\documentclass{article}

\let\saveboldmath\boldmath
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\let\boldmath\saveboldmath
\usepackage{bm}

\DeclareSymbolFont{cmsymbols}{OMS}{cmsy}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{cmsymbols}{bold}{OMS}{cmsy}{b}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet{\mathcal}{cmsymbols}

\begin{document}

Times $\mathcal{ABCD}$ $\bm{\mathcal{ABCD}}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: `mathptmx` has *no* bold math version; in case bold math is needed, the `newtxtext` and `newtxmath` packages should be used.

Comment: Indeed, but `cmsy` (`\mathcal`) has bold version. I don't like `mathptmx` that simply forbid `\boldmath`.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use `\usepackage{newtxtext}` from the `newtx` package, which loads a Times-like font for the text, but shouldn't change the math fonts.