# Using computer modern \rightarrow with fourier font

Tags: fonts, symbols, fourier

I am using the fourier font in a LaTeX document, but instead of the \rightarrow that fourier provides, I need the Computer Modern right arrow.

For example, I need

[image]

instead of:

[image]

I have tried using \DeclareMathSymbol to no avail and am totally stuck -- any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Yah, that sucks. How about showing what you've done in the form of a (perhaps non) [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Quite easy, once you know how to do it. `;-)`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{amsmath}

% load the CM symbol font
\DeclareSymbolFont{arrows}{OMS}{cmsy}{m}{n}
% change the arrows to be taken from the CM symbol font
\DeclareMathSymbol{\leftrightarrow}{\mathrel}{arrows}{"24}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\leftarrow}{\mathrel}{arrows}{"20}
   \let\gets=\leftarrow
\DeclareMathSymbol{\rightarrow}{\mathrel}{arrows}{"21}
   \let\to=\rightarrow
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mapstochar}{\mathrel}{arrows}{"37}
% the bar for making longer arrows
\DeclareMathSymbol{\relbardash}{\mathbin}{arrows}{"00}
\DeclareRobustCommand\relbar{%
  \mathrel{\smash\relbardash}% \smash, because - has the same height as +
}

\begin{document}
$X\to Y\gets Z$

$X\longrightarrow Y\longleftarrow Z$

$x\mapsto f(x)$

$X\xrightarrow{aaaaaaaaa}Y$
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

How to find this solution? Here's a method.

We know that we need a new math symbol font to which assigning the arrows we want to modify. So I looked into `fontmath.ltx`, the file where the standard assignment are found. There I found the line

```
\DeclareSymbolFont{symbols}{OMS}{cmsy}{m}{n}
```

and assigned a new name to the symbol font (I chose `arrows`). Then I looked for `\rightarrow`, `\leftarrow` and `\mapstochar`, which are the basic ingredients for the needed arrow and copied the respective lines by changing `symbols` into `arrows`. I also put the two `\let` instruction to make sure that the aliases `\to` and `\gets` point to the redefined symbols.

Less easy is the question about `\longrightarrow` and `\longleftarrow`. They are built by pasting together a minus sign and an arrow:

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\longrightarrow}{\relbar\joinrel\rightarrow}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\longlefttarrow}{\leftarrow\joinrel\relbar}
```

We need to change also `\relbar`, because `\joinrel` is just a negative spacing. Now, in `fontmath.ltx` we find

```
\DeclareRobustCommand\relbar{%
  \mathrel{\smash-}% \smash, because -has the same height as +
}
```

and we find a problem. This definition uses the minus sign, but we don't want to change the minus sign coming from the Fourier fonts. So I found the line for `-`:

```
\DeclareMathSymbol{-}{\mathbin}{symbols}{"00}
```

and defined a new symbol with the same properties; finally, I redeclared `\relbar` to use it instead of the minus sign:

```
% the bar for making longer arrows
\DeclareMathSymbol{\relbardash}{\mathbin}{arrows}{"00}
\DeclareRobustCommand\relbar{%
  \mathrel{\smash\relbardash}% \smash, because - has the same height as +
}
```

Doing the same with other symbol fonts can be done similarly, by looking at the style files where the correspondence of symbols with triples “math type+math font+slot” is defined.

Comment: How did you find out that the \rightarrow was in slot 21 (and so on for the other symbols)? Is there an easy way of doing this? Thanks!

Comment: @AndrewBate Just find on your computer the file `fontmath.ltx`; I just copied from there changing `symbols` into `arrows` in order to assign the symbols to the new math font just declared.

Comment: amsmath has its own definition of `\relbar` which is not robust and uses `\mathpalette`. It also has its definition of `\longrightarrow` etc... so your code reverts this to the non-amsmath status, I don't know if or where this could show up concretely under certain circumstances.

Comment: @jfbu The `\relbar` redefinition by `amsmath` is just to make the construction compatible with the tricks `amsmath` does when doing `\qopname`; since I *don't* use the minus sign, nothing bad should happen. And I don't redefine `\longrightarrow` nor `\longleftarrow`.

Comment: @jfbu Actually, the `amsmath` definition uses directly `\mathpalette\mathsm@sh`, which is what `\smash` expands to when used in math mode. It would be probably slightly more efficient to use `\mathpalette\mathsm@sh` also here, but less direct for the beginner.

Comment: I do not understand why `\newmcodes@` resets the mathcode of `std@minus` before assigning the `-` in operator names to be from the operator font. The `\mathcode` for `-` has anyhow a scope restricted to the `\mathop` in `\qopname`. Does `amsmath` want to allow `\relbar` in operator names??? Anyhow, this particular thing later broke unicode, and has been patched in `lualatex-math` in particular.

Comment: and thanks for the explanations before that (I forgot). Sorry about `\longrightarrow` I did a mix between your code and your later explanations.

Comment: @jfbu I don't know why `\std@minus` is reset; I can think to some situations where `-` is made math active.

Comment: The `\std@minus` is defined (a priori, once and for all) at begin document with a `\mathchardef` using the then `\mathcode` of `-`. I do not understand why it should be redefined, whatever suffering one may have inflicted to `-` later on. And especially why this should be in `\newmcodes@`.