# Compilation ok with latexmk, file-not-found with pdflatex

Tags: pdftex, latexmk, auxiliary-files, compilation-error, dot2texi

In short: I stumbled upon a case where `latexmk` runs fine,
but `pdflatex` fails, using the command outputted by `latexmk`.

Some details:
my setup is gently exotic but I can't get why this could interfere and why `pdflatex` would only succeed when launched *via* `latexmk`.
The only hint I have,
from my scarce understanding of the sources,
is that `latexmk` can redefine `$ENV{TEXINPUTS}`.
I could not make other/simpler bugging cases than this one,
with `dot2texi` *and* a specific build directory.

Here is the tree of my working directory:

```
.
├── build/
├── dot2texi.sty
└── dot.tex
```

I'm using the `dot2texi.sty` patch from [here](https://github.com/ysalmon/dot2texisty/blob/patch-1/dot2texi.sty) to be able to compile with all the (numerous!) build files sent to the directory `build/`.
I use the settings proposed in [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/388339) answer in the `dot.tex` file:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[inputdir=build/]{dot2texi}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\begin{document}
\begin{dot2tex}[neato]
digraph G { a -> b }
\end{dot2tex}
\end{document}
```

When launching `latexmk -pdf --output-directory=build --shell-escape dot.tex` everything runs as expected.
The numerous build files are sent to `build` and the graph is correctly compiled.

When launching `pdflatex  -recorder -output-directory="build"  --shell-escape "dot.tex"`
(which is what `latexmk` says it runs) I get the following error:

```
Opening dot2tex stream dot-dot2tex-fig1.dot
! LaTeX Error: File `dot-dot2tex-fig1.tex' not found.
```

This buggy behaviour was reproduced on two machines,
under debian and gentoo.
I also tried to play a bit with the `pdflatex` options,
without success.

Definitely not the most critical bug of the century,
but I'd like to understand what I'm doing wrong...

Comment: `--output-directory="build"` will add build as an input directory for pdflatex, but this is not passed to external commands called via shell-escape.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. How do you explain that the compilation works as expected when the same command is called *via* ```latexmk```? I'd expect both or none to fail.

Comment: It probably setups the environment so that the other command see the folder too. But I didn't check what really happen, I only think that it is quite probable that there are differences.

Comment: Thanks. I indeed had checked in the ```latexmk```'s sources that environment variables might be modified. I also have many other use-cases with "regular" standalone tikzpictures built on the fly from a main document. Everything works as I expect, with both ```latexmk``` and ```pdflatex``` using ```\standaloneconfig{`build={latexoptions={--shell-escape -output-directory=build/}}}```.

Comment: Definitely, latexmk sets the environment variable TEXINPUTS to include the build directory.  (It also includes it in BSTINPUTS.) That should explain the different behavior. So if you want pdflatex to have the same behavior as latexmk, you have to set TEXINPUTS yourself.

Comment: @JohnCollins Thanks for the feedback. (And for ```latexmk``` by the way.) It was not clear for me, reading the documentation, that ```latexmk``` would silently redefine ```TEXINPUTS```, without being explicitly asked. Reading the logs, I didn't find any mention of this redefinition of the variables.  Did I miss the info somewhere? I think you could turn your comment into an answer, as it may be useful to others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is indeed a hidden difference in behavior between `pdflatex` invoked by `latexmk` and `pdflatex` invoked by the user with the **identical** command line. This happens because `latexmk` sets the environment variable `TEXINPUTS` to include the build directory in the search path for TeX source files.  (Strictly speaking it's the `aux_dir` that's used.  But that equals the `out_dir` if only the `out_dir` is set, as in this case.)

The changed environment variable is passed to any command invoked by `pdflatex`.  Then `dot2tex` works properly when a build directory is used.  If you want the same behavior when you start `pdflatex` yourself from the command line, then you have to first modify (or set) `TEXINPUTS`.

**Historical Note**: The original reason for `latexmk` to set `TEXINPUTS` is that the same variable is an analogous problem with `dvips`.  The trigger for this was incorrect behavior by the `FeynMP` package, according to my notes from 2011.  With `dot2tex` we now see another version of the same problem.  It was probably in the back of my mind, that setting `TEXINPUTS` would solve other similar problems, as we now see with `dot2tex`.

Comment: Much clearer like that. Interesting historical note. Would it be worth telling the users in ```latexmk```'s log when a variable is modified?

Comment: I've done that, and the result will be in the next release.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Glad if it helps! It sounds useful to be able to reproduce step by step everything ```latexmk``` does, just reading the log. Thanks!