# Calligraphic symbols are too fancy with mathptmx package

Tags: fonts, mathcal, alphabet, calligraphy

I am using the `mathptmx` package because I prefer my text to be in Times New Roman. However, `\mathcal` provides in this package "super calligraphic" symbols looking like the ones obtained by using `\mathscr` from the `mathrsfs` package.

My **question** is therefore: How can I get the F for, e.g., the Fourier transform to look like `\mathcal F` in default mode (see for an example https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Symbols:%5Cmathcal). Similarly, for the Schwarz space I want the S to look like `\mathcal S` in default mode.

If I may add a **second question**: what exactly is the purpose the `mathptmx` package, apart from changing the font style to Times New Roman?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate : [Resetting mathcal font to default](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67881/resetting-mathcal-font-to-default)

Comment: If you really love Times (*de gustibus non est disputandum*…), you should give a try at the `newtxtext`, `newtxmath`  packages, based on `TeX Gyre Termes`, a  Times clone, which has more possibilities.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**To grab the whole alphabet**

```
\documentclass{article}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\altmathcal}{OMS}{cmsy}{m}{n}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\begin{document}
$\altmathcal{F}\mathcal{F}$

$\altmathcal{S}\mathcal{S}$

abc\fontfamily{cmr}\selectfont abc
\end{document}
```

### [image]

**To grab just one or two characters**

You could save them each in a box before loading `mathptmx`.  No need to worry about smaller mathstyles, as `\mathcal` does not seem to support them anyhow.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newsavebox\mcFcontent
\savebox\mcFcontent{$\mathcal{F}$}
\newcommand\mcF{\usebox{\mcFcontent}}
\newsavebox\mcScontent
\savebox\mcScontent{$\mathcal{S}$}
\newcommand\mcS{\usebox{\mcScontent}}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\begin{document}
$\mcF\mathcal{F}$

$\mcS\mathcal{S}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

One can make it a macro `\savemathcal{}` and use them with `\altmathcal{}`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\savemathcal[1]{%
  \expandafter\newsavebox\csname mc#1content\endcsname%
  \expandafter\savebox\csname mc#1content\endcsname{$\mathcal{#1}$}%
  \expandafter\newcommand\csname mc#1\endcsname{%
    \expandafter\usebox\expandafter{\csname mc#1content\endcsname}}%
}
\newcommand\altmathcal[1]{\csname mc#1\endcsname}
\savemathcal{F}
\savemathcal{S}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\begin{document}
$\altmathcal{F}\mathcal{F}$

$\altmathcal{S}\mathcal{S}$
\end{document}
```

As to your second question, https://ctan.org/search/?phrase=mathptmx says

```
Pack­age math­ptmx
Use Times as de­fault text font, and pro­vide maths sup­port
```

Comment: Is there short way to do this for every letter in the alphabet? This way I'd have the calligraphic versions of both font styles (Times and default font) available. Many thanks!

Comment: @Apollo13 For text fonts, the way to do it is just select the appropriate font family.  In your document, for example, try `abc\fontfamily{cmr}\selectfont abc`.  You will see the times abc, followed by the computer modern abc.

Comment: With math alphabets, there is a more complicated `\DeclareMathAlphabet` command, except that I did not know the name of the original `\mathcal` font to do so, so I used boxes instead.

Comment: @Apollo13 See my revision

Comment: With my new revision, you need do none of the above.  The one line `\DeclareMathAlphabet{\altmathcal}{OMS}{cmsy}{m}{n}` makes all the original `\mathcal` letters available as `\altmathcal`.  The line `\fontfamily{cmr}\selectfont` changes all the letters back to computer modern font, the default LaTeX font.

Comment: @Apollo13 After changing to `cmr` font, one can return to times with `\fontfamily{ptm}\selectfont`.