# New locally defined mathcal font for math equations

Tags: fonts, equations, math-fonts

I want to make use of math fonts of mathcal namely: "pxtx" and "dutchcal" which is elaborated in this nice [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/58124/120126). However, I don't want to change the standard mathcal font but just use locally these fonts. How can I do that?

Some additional info. due to @Mico:

1) I use amsfont package. The F in the figure below is in the standard standard mathcal font:

[image]

2) document class: `IEEEtran`

3) `pdfLaTeX`

4) I use `\mathbb`

Comment: Please tell us what the "standard mathcal" font of your document is at present.

Comment: Please also indicate (a) which document class you employ, (b) whether you employ pdfLaTeX, XeLaTeX, or LuaLaTeX (or something else entirely) to compile your document, and (c) if your document makes use of `\mathfrak` and/or `\mathbb`. (The reason I ask question (c) is that it's not all that straightforward to have several script or calligraphic math alphabets all at once.)

Comment: I added the information that you asked. Thanks.

Comment: I’m not sure what you mean, “Just use locally.” Do you actually need to use three different calligraphic alphabets in the same document?

Comment: @Davislor -- (totally off topic) The AMS once published a small monograph in which the authors had used five different lowercase script "p"s (no other letters), each with a very distinct (but somewhat related) definition, and refused to change their notation.  I'm not at all sure how many readers were able to distinguish between the various shapes; some of them were different only in very subtle ways, so when one of the more similar glyphs appeared in isolation, I hope that it was clear from context which was meant.  Authors have their own ideas, and often won't budge.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Well, if anyone considers that a model to be emulated, consider me an enabler?

Answer (score 4):

I’m not sure I understand your question properly.  If you need to use two different calligraphic alphabets in the same document, the easiest way to accomplish this is to load one as `\mathcal` and the other as `\mathscr` in `mathalpha`.  (On older installations, you might need to use its older name, `mathalfa`.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[cal = pxtx, scr = dutchcal]{mathalpha}

\begin{document}

pxtx: \( \mathcal{ABC} \)

dutchcal: \( \mathscr{ABC} \)

\end{document}
```

[image: Font sample]

However, I’m not sure whether you meant that you need to use **three** very-similar calligraphic alphabets in the same document.  (Unless it’s a specimen of different math scripts, I can’t imagine why.)

In that case, use `\DeclareMathAlphabet` with the proper family and encoding names. I adapted the code in `mathalpha.sty`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

% Based on the code from mathalpha.sty:

  \DeclareFontFamily{U}{dutchcal}{\skewchar \font =45}
  \DeclareFontShape{U}{dutchcal}{m}{n}{
    <-> dutchcal-r}{}
  \DeclareFontShape{U}{dutchcal}{b}{n}{
    <-> dutchcal-b}{}
  \DeclareMathAlphabet{\mdutchcal}{U}{dutchcal}{m}{n}
  \SetMathAlphabet{\mdutchcal}{bold}{U}{dutchcal}{b}{n}
  \DeclareMathAlphabet{\mdutchbcal} {U}{dutchcal}{b}{n}

  \DeclareFontFamily{U}{txcal}{\skewchar \font =45}
  \DeclareFontShape{U}{txcal}{m}{n}{
    <-> txr-cal}{}
  \DeclareFontShape{U}{txcal}{b}{n}{
    <-> txb-cal}{}
  \DeclareMathAlphabet{\mtxcal}{U}{txcal}{m}{n}
  \SetMathAlphabet{\mtxcal}{bold}{U}{txcal}{b}{n}
  \DeclareMathAlphabet{\mtxbcal} {U}{txcal}{b}{n}

\begin{document}

pxtx: \( \mtxcal{ABC} \)

dutchcal: \( \mdutchcal{ABC} \)

mathcal: \( \mathcal{ABC} \)

\end{document}
```

[image: Three calligraphic alphabets]

If one of your packages is changing `\mathcal` and you need to restore it, [see this question.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67881/resetting-mathcal-font-to-default)  You can also save the original definition of `\mathcal` with `\let` and `\renewcommand\mathcal`.

Be aware that legacy LaTeX only allows you to declare a limited number of math alphabets.  One way to work around this is to load a script font as a text font (for example, a Fraktur font from `oldgerm`) and use it in math mode by wrapping it in `\text` from `amsmath`.

In the modern toolchain with `unicode-math`, you can use `\setmathfontface` to create as many new math alphabets as you want.  You can also `\setmathfont[range=cal, Scale=MatchUppercase]{Some Font}` and `\setmathfont[range=scr, Scale=MatchUppercase]{Another Font}` to load a new script alphabet.  Indeed, if you don’t do one or the other, they’ll be set to the same face by default.